# Adding subdomain to virtual host - Apache just says "It Works"

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, subdomain

I have added `sub.example.com` as a new A record in my DNS manager, and created the virtual host file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName sub.example.com
    ServerAlias sub.example.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/sub.example.com/public_html/
    ErrorLog /srv/www/sub.example.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /srv/www/sub.example.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

At the moment the page just shows the Apache "It Works".

The main site `example.com` is working with this virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
     ServerName example.com
     ServerAlias www.example.com
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/example.com/public_html/
     ErrorLog /srv/www/example.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /srv/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Why does sub.example.com not get picked up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make an addition at the top :

```
NameVirtualHost   x.x.x.x:80
```

where the `x.x.x.x` is your ip address.

Also, keep in mind that you need to restart your apache, and make sure that your DNS is properly resolving.

Comment: Thanks! It was the IP address that I needed to add. Why would the * not work? I thought that was a wildcard for the IP?